# Bash extracting a string after two specific keywords and writing it to a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to write a script that extracts a key specified to a device from a file and writes that key into a file. This key is after two specific keywords and looks like such:

```
"nickname":"A1", "afsklfu4a":uaepa /alsejrta, "aefhjasef":aesrhkjsdfj aas////jaek, "iden":"ThisIsTheKey", "adefrapw":"aieojdiasf", "nickname":"A2", "fakshfra":"qwfjlasefawe", "afliwuehfla":"alweuhfukqw4", "iden":"ThisIsAnotherKey"
```

I want the writing to a file to look like such:

```
A1=ThisIsTheKey
A2=ThisIsAnotherKey
.... and so on 
A=5=ThisIsAnotherKey
```

Note: There is a maximum of 5 devices per letter, so the next series would be `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, `B5` and so on for the next.

I was thinking of maybe using `grep` or `awk` in this situation and I also read that sed can be used to add text in between other text, so that might help for the part where I have to write to a file; any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep and GNU sed:

```
grep -oP '"(nickname|iden)":"\K.*?(?=")' file.txt | sed 'N;y/\n/=/' > out.txt
```

Output to out.txt:

```
A1=ThisIsTheKey
A2=ThisIsAnotherKey
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works great, however, i failed to notice that the device id is before the device name, so when I output, I get this: ThisIsTheKey=A1 ThisIsAnotherKey=A2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace `sed 'N;y/\n/=/'` by `sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2=\1/'` to swap lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [root@test /tmp]$ awk -vRS='"(nickname|iden)":"' -F\" 'NF&&!s{s=$1"=";next}s{print s$1;s=c}' a
A1=ThisIsTheKey
A2=ThisIsAnotherKey
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"iden":/\n/;s/.*"nickname":"([^"]*)".*\n"([^"]*)"/\1=\2\n/;/[^=\n]*=[^=\n]*\n/P;D' file
```

Construct from a pair of `iden` and `nickname` the required string and print each separately.

N.B. the commands iterate shortening the current line until no further matches occur.